# Bad configuration: cannot ssh

Tags: macos, ssh

As described in many other posts, after upgrading to MacOS Sierra I modified the ssh config file like so:

```
Host me
HostName login.hpc.ugent.be
User vscxxxxx
Port 22

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

Still I get the following error:

```
$ssh -Y vscxxxxx@login.hpc.ugent.be
/Users/manfredo/.ssh/config: line 8: Bad configuration option: usekeychain
/Users/manfredo/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -V` and `type ssh`? Or do you know whether you have non-system-default ssh installed?

Comment: OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

Comment: BTW, the config file shown above seems to have incorrect indentation. Was this intentional?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the `UseKeychain yes` line from your configuration. The update broke existing setup by removing this option.

Comment: This is probably false, assuming we are talking the system-provided ssh. What update broke it? Or do you mean some non-Apple ssh update? I'm on up-to-date macOS and having `UseKeychain yes` or `usekeychain yes` give no errors.

Comment: That actually works. I don't really know what caused it to stop working, the only thing is I updated my macport packages today.

Comment: This answer removes useful functionality, use the other answers which actually work.

Answer (score 9):

Apple's documentation on [OpenSSH updates in macOS 10.12.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) states that:

> If you are sharing your ssh configuration with systems running older versions of OpenSSH that don't understand the UseKeychain option, you can specify the IgnoreUnknown option to keep your configuration compatible with both new and old versions.

So the trick is that in your ssh config file, add `IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain` like below:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: This worked for me but only for the first directive, still got "Bad configuration option: usekeychain" even though I added the "IgnoreUnknown Usekeychain" in all 3 it's used in.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `/usr/bin/ssh` for the commands, it works. The default path in 10.12 puts `/usr/local/bin` at the top so any other version of `ssh` will not work with that option, since it's specific to the mac system.

Comment: to add on to this, simply `nano ~/.bash_profile` then make sure `/usr/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` if they aren't in your `$PATH` declaration at all simply add both with them in that order.  Something like `export PATH="~/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/:$PATH` then `source ~/.bash_profile` this resolved it for me